# Cannot connect project to a SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, mdf

I have a problem while trying to copy my project folder to another hard drive. My project in Visual Studio is defined in `h:\` and while run exe file project no any problem but while copy folder project to another hard drive I have a problem to connect the application to SQL Server.

See these screenshots:

- http://upload.tehran98.com/img1/f9kio8ssjofg1lhkjdg.jpg
- http://upload.tehran98.com/img1/k6ajdb22xhdjrgcn419.jpg

For example in login form and in login button my code is:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim conn As New SqlConnection("Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=" + Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\Database\Automation.mdf;Database=Automation;Trusted_Connection=Yes;")
        s2 = "Select count( * ) from Login where UserName = '" & TextBox1.Text & "' and Password = '" & TextBox2.Text & "'"
        Dim com As New SqlCommand(s2, conn)
        Dim res As Object
        conn.Open()
        res = com.ExecuteScalar()
        conn.Close()
        If res = 1 Then
            MsgBox("Welcome Dear " + TextBox1.Text, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Login Successful")
            us = TextBox1.Text
            If us = "admin" Then
                Main.Label4.Text = "ADMINISTRATOR"
            Else
                Main.Label4.Text = "USER"
                us = TextBox1.Text
                Main.Button3.Enabled = False
                Main.Button5.Enabled = False
                Main.Button9.Enabled = False
            End If
            Main.Show()
            Me.Hide()
        Else
            MsgBox("Invalid User OR Password", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Attention Please")
            TextBox1.Text = ""
            TextBox2.Text = ""
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Look at your definition for `SqlConnection`. It includes `relative` paths. Do you have all these objects on *the other* hard drives?

Comment: This looks like VBA. You should update it with this tag.

Comment: Yes all these object are on the other hard drive ... look pictrue

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify where the database is, you can't use **Environment.CurrentDirectory**. CurrentDirectory uses the path of the current working directory. So either move the database to the same hard drive or change the path to your database.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.currentdirectory.aspx

Comment: Thanks... But To Solve This Problme Should be changed In My Code ?

Comment: Either change your code, so it points to the correct directory. Or move the database.